# How to fix - Filling buffer causes hardfault handler error

Tags: c, buffer

I am trying to fill a buffer from the with data which i will then decode to extract latitude and longitude.

The data is coming through the uart one character at a time. I  have tried to fill a buffer one character at a time and one the '\n' is found indicate that the buffer is full, indicating the decode of buffer can happen.

The buffer is being filled with my current code however after about a minute of running it causes a hardfault_handler to occur, I am not sure what is the cause. I have attached my current code please advise.

Thanks in advance.

```
char buffer[70];
bool buffer_full = false;
uint8_t data=0;
uint8_t *data_ptr = 0;

bool valid_data(uint8_t character){
    bool btemp = false;
if (isalnum(character)){
    btemp = true;
}else if(character ==','){
    btemp = true;
}else if(character =='\r'){
    btemp = true;
}else if(character =='\n'){
    btemp = true;
}else if(character =='*'){
    btemp = true;
}
else if(character =='$'){
        btemp = true;
}

return btemp;
```

}

```
void UART7_Rx(uint8_t rx_char){

//Anything received here means the GPS receiver is on
GPS_connection.on = true;

if (data == buffer_size-2){
        data=0;
    }

if (valid_data(rx_char)==true){
        if (buffer_full == false && rx_char != '\0') {
            buffer[data] = rx_char;
            data++;
            if (rx_char == '\n' || rx_char =='\r' || data == buffer_size-2){
            buffer[data+1] = '\0';
            data =0;
            buffer_full = true;
            }
        }
}
```

}
note i do set buffer_full = false and data = 0 and data_ptr=0 when decode is complete.

Comment: This comparison if (isalnum(character)==true){ is incorrect. It is not necessary that the function will return exactly 1 instead of any non-zero value.

Comment: Your buffer has space for 70 bytes.  The first thing I notice is that there's no code that checks that you're not writing more than 70 bytes to it.

Comment: Aside: I'm not sure what the purpose of `data_ptr` is, but setting it to `&rx_char` (and later, incrementing it) does not seem very useful, in particular because it will be either invalid or null when the function returns.

Comment: @OHNDOE This statement data_ptr++; does not make sense.

Comment: What Vlad is saying is that `isalnum` might return, say, 8 when it matches a character, not necessarily 1.  So you should write `if (isalnum(character))`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i have changed the isalnum check

Comment: @SteveSummit i have added a check for 70 bytes and reset the data index back to 0

Comment: remove the data_ptr++ thought i need to increment the address. however i see that is not required.

Comment: After changes still get hardfault handler.. thanks for all the recommendations so far.

Comment: After changes still get hardfault handler.. thanks for all the recommendations so far.

Comment: Sometimes lines are terminated by `\n`.  Sometimes lines are terminated by `\r\n`.  And sometimes lines are terminated by `\r`.  Are you successfully reading *any* lines?  If your receiver is emitting only `\r`, you'll never successfully read a line, and (with your original code) the buffer would always overflow.

Comment: I wouldn't advise setting the `data` index back to 0 if you hit 70 characters.  That means you'll ignore lines longer than 70 characters.  You have several choices: (1) ignore the too-long line, (2) truncate the too-long line, (3) split the too-long line, (4) make `buffer` bigger.  I recommend both (4) and (2). And think about this: I just looked at a GPS transcript I had handy, and I see plenty of lines -- including the vital $GPGGA lines -- that are between 70 and 90 characters long.

Comment: @SteveSummit see updated code. I have ensure that the buffer wont overflow. i will increase buffer to 150. BUt still running into an error

Comment: @SteveSummit how do i truncate the buffer

Comment: @SteveSummit note i am reading the data line by line. then decode and if the i am done decoding then i clear the buffer full flag and fill the buffer again.

Comment: Your revised code checks `buffer_size` in two places.  (I assume `buffer_size` is defined correctly.)  The first test will cause long lines to be ignored.  The second test will cause long lines to be split.  Choose one or the other.  To truncate: when you hit `buffer_size`, stop storing characters and stop incrementing `data`, but don't set `buffer_full` until you find the `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: @SteveSummit thank you for all your help. the problem has disappeared after having only one buffer size check